# ActionScript 3: How can the re-sizing of the width of a parent object by its child be prevented?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
if(_ss.x >= _l.getWidth()){
            _ss.x = _l.getWidth();
            _vx *= -1;
```

_ss is the child object of _l.
_l's original width is 1024px.
When ss.x is greater than 1024px the _l's width
is expanded by the same amount of pixels. However, strangely the 
Parent, _l, which is essentially a background and container, does not resize visually. The _l.width property, however, increases when its object child _ss, visually a space ship, exceeds the _l.width's original pixel width of 1024.

I want _ss to be prevented from moving beyond its parent's original width of 1024px. I am new to ActionScript. What can be done?

Comment: It would be easier to follow if you gave your variables meaningful names, personally I re-read your question several times and found it really hard to follow. Also, `getWidth()` is not an AS3 API, what code defines that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, you're noticing that when a child size changes it is reflected by it's parent `DisplayObject`/`width` and `height` properties, but does not visually change the parent. This is expected, a display object's `width` and `height` (and `getBounds()`) reflects the measured size of its contents, and there is no automatic layout of graphics when size changes in this way (such as drawing a background that fills the container bounds).

In other words:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
container.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
trace(container.width, container.height); // 100 100

var child:Shape = new Shape();
child.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
child.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
trace(child.width, child.height); // 500 500

container.addChild(child);
trace(container.width, container.height); // 500 500
```

You can't prevent this behavior in a general sense, but you can override it with an extended class. For example:

```
class UISprite extends Sprite {
    private var _width:Number = 0;

    override public function set width(value:Number):void {
        _width = value;
    }

    override public function get width():Number { 
        return _width;
    }
}
```

Now a `UISprite` instance has a "virtualized" width that doesn't reflect the measured size. You can set it to be anything you like, regardless of the actual size of its contents:

```
var ui:UISprite = new UISprite();
trace(ui.width); // 0
ui.width = 100;
trace(ui.width); // 100
```

You can add things to it and it won't effect the `width` property:

```
var child:Shape = new Shape();
child.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
child.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
ui.addChild(child);
trace(ui.width); // 100
```

Flex makes heavy use of this sort of thing to provide layout features.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You Aaron this is very useful information. The child's size, in my code, however, is not being resized but moved inside the parent by its X and Y properties. However, the principle and spirit of your explanation is still valid.

Comment: Yep the same thing applies if you move children of a container. Basically, think of the bounding rectangle of the entire container's contents, and the width and height of those bounds becomes the containers width and height properties.

Comment: Thank You Aaron. This is very useful informtion. The child's size, in my code, however, is not being resized but moved inside the parent by its X and Y properties. However, the principle and spirit of your explanation is still valid. Actually, just before reading your response, I solved what proved to be a very easy problem. I simply stored the value of the parent's width and height in variables of the child before they could be changed by the child's activity. Thus now the child can't move past its parent's width and height. Thank You for you're response. It is the theory behind the answer.